# SQL Compare Data of a table and view

Tags: sql, sql-server, view, compare

Say I have table A which has data for every couple of minutes. For Example for a product table A can have data something like below

- 1/4/2016 00:04:00 - 15
- 1/4/2016 00:08:23 - 10
- 1/4/2016 04:18:43 - 17
- 1/6/2016 06:06:24 - 5 etc...

Then I have a view which calculate Average value for each product for each day.
ex:

- Product1  1/4/2016 - 30
- Product1  1/5/2016 - 60
- Product2  1/8/2016 - 40

I have about 10000 products and have to calculate Avg for about 30 columns. and roughly I'll have 6 months data. So view will return huge number of rows.

Now I have a requirement to write a SQL job which will execute hourly and get data from above view and Insert data to a new table (Table B). Table B have the exactly the same schema as the view. I have written a MERGE statement with the job step and successfully inserted/updated data to Table B.

My problem is It's taking hours to complete the job. The problem is view has all 6 months data and Insert if it's not on target table and update if it's already on target table. I don't want to do this as my Older data is not going to change. How can I get only the data which is not on Table B and insert/update them? In other words, How can I get only the data which is not already added and not identical from the view. (I tried EXCEPT statement and had no luck as I have to compare all 30 columns)

P.S I have ProductID and ProductionDate as the primaryKey on Table B.

Comment: Since you didn't really post any details here I am not sure what you are looking for. We can't really offer much help without at least table definitions and an explanation of what you are trying to do. This would be a great place to start. http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Comment: 10000 products * 188  days  < 2 000 000 rows. What if just truncate  the target table and populate it from scratch every hour? It hardly will take much time.

Comment: The information provided is fairly insufficient to give you a detailed accurate answer, but if you don't want to provide specific schema details (and potentially the logic you're using to create the data set), can you at least tell us where the significant delay occurs? Assuming this data does not need to be always available, if you did truncate table B and populate from scratch every time (per @Serg suggestion) would this work or is the logic to create your resultset part of the large delay?

Comment: Also, is the view schemaBound (aka With SchemaBinding) and if yes, does it have an index to mirror the index on your Table?